# PHP + MongoDB: how to search for a variable text?

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using PHP 5.6.16 accessing MongoDB 3.2 via the MongoDB driver for PHP (php_mongo-1.6.14-5.6-ts-vc11-x64), and I've already been able to create a few pages.

I need to create a page that lists the employees registered in MongoDB from a text entered by the user, for example, the first name (the name field in MongoDB stores the full name).

Using the mongoshell, I can execute this query in the following command

```
db.employee.find("name":/Rogerio/)
```

If I try to pass the full name as a parameter, logically the search works (see full PHP code below).

```
<?php
    $m = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    $collection = $m->mydb->employees;

    echo "<form action='' method=post>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='name'>";
    echo "<input type=submit name=search value=Search>";
    echo "</form>";

    if (isset($_POST['search'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $employees = $collection->find(array('name' => $name));

    echo "<table border=0 rules=rows width=600>";
    foreach ($employees as $emp){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>{$emp['nome']}</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

To be able to search for a part of the name, I tried to use the following code to set `$name`:

```
$name = "/" . $_POST['name'] . "/";
```

but it did not work.

How to pass this kind of parameter to the PHP driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with

```
$employees = $collection->find(array('name' => array("$regex" => $name)));
```

With this option you will search using regular expressions, it´s more or less equivalent to "LIKE" statements in MySQL.

You can use this in mongo shell as follows:

`db.employee.find({"name":{"$regex": "Rogerio"}})`

Comment: It worked! Thank you!  I just needed to correct a small detail: '$regex' (not double quotation marks)

Comment: Yes! the correct one is: $employees = $collection->find(array('name' => array('$regex' => $name)));